# Can we find a basis $B$ of $M$ such that $|B|=1$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices, ring-theory, modules

Let $M=\mathbb{(Z[\sqrt{-5} ])^2/ \begin{bmatrix} 2 \\ 1+\sqrt{-5} \end{bmatrix} Z[\sqrt{-5}]}$, a quotient $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]$-module. Can we find a basis $B$ of $M$ such that $|B|=1$?

I believe that the answer is "no," but I am having trouble proving this.

If I start by assuming $B=\{\begin{bmatrix} a \\ b \end{bmatrix}+\begin{bmatrix} 2 \\ 1+\sqrt{-5} \end{bmatrix} \mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]\}$ is a basis for $M$, it is not clear to me how I may obtain a contradiction from this. Please help.

Comment: Let $a=\sqrt 5$, $R=\mathbb Z[a]$ the ring of integers in $\mathbb Q(a)$, $M=R^{\times 2}$ the free $R$-module of rank two. We build the quotient w.r.t. $R(2,1+a)$. This is an $R$-module, rank one, let $B=\{b\$ be the system of one generator. What is $|b|$? The minimal distance (w.r.t.$R\subset \mathbb C$) from $b$ to $R(2,1+a)$?

Comment: Sorry for the above... could not re-edit in time. What is $|b|$? The minimal distance from $b$ to the module $R(2,1+a)$, where we consider $R\subset\mathbb C$?

Comment: $|B|$ is just the cardinality of $B$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $$t=\sqrt{-5}$$ to simplify further typing. Let $R=\mathbb Z[t]$. Assume as in the post that
$$\begin{bmatrix}a\\b\end{bmatrix}$$
freely generates the quotient module
$$M=R^2\Big/R \begin{bmatrix}2\\1+t\end{bmatrix}\ .$$
Then the canoical vectors of $R^2$, mapped to $M$, admit (unique) representations
\begin{align}
\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\end{bmatrix} 
&= p\begin{bmatrix}a\\b\end{bmatrix} + q\begin{bmatrix}2\\1+t\end{bmatrix}
= \begin{bmatrix}a & 2\\b & 1+t\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}p\\q\end{bmatrix}
\\\\
\begin{bmatrix}0\\1\end{bmatrix} 
&= r\begin{bmatrix}a\\b\end{bmatrix} + s\begin{bmatrix}2\\1+t\end{bmatrix}
= \begin{bmatrix}a & 2\\b & 1+t\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}r\\s\end{bmatrix}
\\\\
&\text{ or in one block}
\\\\
\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&1\end{bmatrix} 
&=  \begin{bmatrix}a & 2\\b & 1+t\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}p&r\\q&s\end{bmatrix}
\end{align}
Now we pass to determinants. Since all entries live in $R$, on the R.H.S. we have a product of two units. This shows that $2,1+t$ generate a unit in $R$, i.e. they can be used to generate $1$, i.e. $(2,1+t)=R\cong\mathbb Z[T]/(T^2+5)$. Taking this isomorphism modulo $2$, we get that $(1+T)$ is a unit (i.e. it generates the one) in $\mathbb F_2[T]/(T^2 +5)=\mathbb F_2[T]/(T+1)^2$. Contradiction.